# source parameter not specified cake

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

using azure devops to build a pipeline. pipeline uses cake scripts to build and publish. facing issue with publish package. below is the diagnostic of publish of nu get step.

```
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8150943Z NuGet
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8151140Z ========================================
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8151688Z Executing task: NuGet
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8195231Z PushNuGet
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8283167Z Pushing NuGet file C:/__w/2/a/build/A.SDK.TestLibrary/nuget/A.TestLibrary.SDK.1.4.2-abranch-15524.nupkg
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8331210Z No Source property has been set.  Depending on your configuration, this may cause problems.
2019-09-16T10:00:32.8620102Z Executing: "C:/__w/2/a/build/tools/NuGet.exe" push "C:/__w/2/a/build/A.SDK.TestLibrary/nuget/A.TestLibrary.SDK.1.4.2-abranch-15524.nupkg" -NonInteractive
2019-09-16T10:00:33.3578097Z Source parameter was not specified.
2019-09-16T10:00:33.3864258Z An error occurred when executing task 'NuGet'.
2019-09-16T10:00:33.3996249Z Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Cake.Core.CakeException: NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> source parameter not specified cake

Just like the error message shows,

> Source parameter was not specified

And your nuget command line is:

```
"C:/__w/2/a/build/tools/NuGet.exe" push "C:/__w/2/a/build/A.SDK.TestLibrary/nuget/A.TestLibrary.SDK.1.4.2-abranch-15524.nupkg"
```

Indeed, it does not specify the source of the push command.

To resolve this issue, you should specify the source in that command:

```
nuget.exe push "YourPackageHere" -source "xxxx"
```

Check the document [push command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks,actually the nuget command was called by a cake file which was somehow missing the source parameter. I had to use nuget task from azure instead of cake,which resolved the issue.